# React native: How can I divided five Rows in Grid view?

Tags: react-native

I am Developing Sample Grid View Project in Grid view. I am Getting two Rows in grid view. but i want displayed in three rows

here this is my Code:

```
var CELLS_PER_ROW = 2;

 <GridView
            key={this.props.key}
           items={this.state.dataSource}
          itemsPerRow={CELLS_PER_ROW}
          renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
           style={{padding:15}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign CELLS_PER_ROW with number of rows you want. Here is the code

```
 `var CELLS_PER_ROW = 3; // number of rows you want

 <GridView
            key={this.props.key}
           items={this.state.dataSource}
          itemsPerRow={CELLS_PER_ROW}
          renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
           style={{padding:15}}/>`
```

Hope it works for you :-) .